# What's wrong with my disk and apfs volumes?

Tags: apfs, diskutil

I'm learning/trying `diskutil`, `newfs_apfs` and other disk command on macOS.
My idea is actually this:

a) Create a 1 GiB container

b) Add 5 volumes of 200 MiB size in the 1 GiB container

I run these commands.

Delete container

```
diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk5 Container1
```

OK

Create container

```
diskutil apfs createContainer disk0s1
```

OK

Now, I start to create the volumes, 200 MiB each (1 GiB can contain 5 volumes of 200 MiB)

```
newfs_apfs -v "Volume1" -s 200M -A disk5
```

OK

```
newfs_apfs -v "Volume2" -s 200M -A disk5
```

OK

```
newfs_apfs -v "Volume3" -s 200M -A disk5
newfs_apfs: unable to format volume inside /dev/disk5: Result too large
```

Why?
The command `diskutil list` reports this situation:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.1 GB     disk0
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         1.1 GB     disk0s1

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.1 GB     disk5
                                 Physical Store disk0s1
   1:                APFS Volume Volume1                 209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume Volume2                 209.7 MB   disk5s2
```

As you can see the container's volume uses only 420 MB of space
and I have at least space for two other volumes.
What's wrong?

Comment: 1 GiB is to small for your experiment. Try again using a 1 TiB disk and 200 GiB volumes. You should be able to get 5 volumes. However, the fifth volume will have to be smaller than 200 MiB.

Comment: Please add this as answer, so I can vote and close question

Comment: I guess when I posted my previous comment, I used a 1 TB disk. In my answer, I used a 1 TiB disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by creating a 1 GiB sparse disk image which contains a GPT with single empty APFS container. The commands are given below. Note that for 1 GiB disks, an EFI partition is not created by the `diskutil erasedisk` verb.

```
hdiutil create -size 1g -type SPARSE -layout none -ov MyGiB 
hdiutil attach -nomount MyGiB.sparseimage
diskutil erasedisk jhfs+ %noformat% gpt disk2
diskutil apfs createcontainer disk2s1
diskutil list external
```

Below are the is the output from entering the above commands.

```
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % hdiutil create -size 1g -type SPARSE -layout none -ov MyGiB 
created: /Users/davidanderson/Desktop/MyGiB.sparseimage
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % hdiutil attach -nomount MyGiB.sparseimage
/dev/disk2                                              
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % diskutil erasedisk jhfs+ %noformat% gpt disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Finished erase on disk2
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % diskutil apfs createcontainer disk2s1
Creating container with disk2s1
Started APFS operation on disk2s1
Creating a new empty APFS Container
Unmounting Volumes
Switching disk2s1 to APFS
Creating APFS Container
Created new APFS Container disk3
Disk from APFS operation: disk3
Finished APFS operation on disk2s1
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % diskutil list external   
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.1 GB     disk2
   1:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         1.1 GB     disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.1 GB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s1
```

With the disk now initialized, I will start adding APFS volumes without reserving space.

```
newfs_apfs -v "Volume1" -A disk3
```

OK

```
newfs_apfs -v "Volume2" -A disk3
```

OK

```
newfs_apfs -v "Volume3" -A disk3
newfs_apfs: unable to format volume inside /dev/disk3: Result too large
```

I think the OP made the assumption that the reserving of 200 MiB per volume was the problem. I think the problem is that a container of only 1 GiB limits the maximum volumes to 2.

Before proceeding, I entered the following command to eject `disk2`, which also ejects `disk3`.

```
diskutil eject disk2
```

### Redoing the Experiment with a 1 TiB Disk and 200 GiB Volumes

Let me start by creating a 1 TiB sparse bundle disk image which contains a GPT with single empty APFS container. The commands are given below. Note that for 1 TiB disks, a 200 MiB EFI partition is created by the `diskutil erasedisk` verb.

```
hdiutil create -size 1t -type SPARSEBUNDLE -layout none -ov MyTiB 
hdiutil attach -nomount MyTiB.sparsebundle
diskutil erasedisk jhfs+ %noformat% gpt disk2
diskutil apfs createcontainer disk2s2
diskutil list external
```

The output from the above commands is basically the same as before, with the exception of the `diskutil list external` output, which is given below.

```
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % diskutil list external
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.1 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         1.1 TB     disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.1 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
```

Below, I keep making 200 GiB volumes until something goes wrong.

```
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % newfs_apfs -v "Volume1" -s 200G -A disk3 
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % newfs_apfs -v "Volume2" -s 200G -A disk3 
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % newfs_apfs -v "Volume3" -s 200G -A disk3 
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % newfs_apfs -v "Volume4" -s 200G -A disk3 
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % newfs_apfs -v "Volume5" -s 200G -A disk3 
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % newfs_apfs -v "Volume6" -s 200G -A disk3 
newfs_apfs: unable to format volume inside /dev/disk3: No space left on device
```

After creating 5 volumes of 214.7 GB each, there is 25.8 GB left, which is more than enough to support the GPT, the 200 MiB EFI partition and any other space needed by the APFS container. The exact computation is shown below.

```
1 TiB - (5 x 200 GiB) = 24 GiB
```

Below is the output from `diskutil list disk3` and `diskutil apfs list disk3`.

```
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % diskutil list disk3   
/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.1 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Volume1⁩                 214.7 GB   disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Volume2⁩                 214.7 GB   disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Volume3⁩                 214.7 GB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Volume4⁩                 214.7 GB   disk3s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Volume5⁩                 214.7 GB   disk3s5

davidanderson@Davids-Mac ~ % diskutil apfs list disk3
|
+-- Container disk3 02B7FC98-230C-4FCD-8B23-FB1A96081B3F
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk3
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      1099301871616 B (1.1 TB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   1073958289408 B (1.1 TB) (97.7% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       25343582208 B (25.3 GB) (2.3% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk2s2 3FECC3C1-E6B9-41D5-BCA0-6859B6C8819A
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk2s2
    |   Size:                       1099301871616 B (1.1 TB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk3s1 C6D7C2C5-5040-428F-AA4B-9CF348DF48D0
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Volume1 (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Reserve:          214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Quota:            214748364800 B (214.7 GB) (100.0% reached)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk3s2 8DD3AB61-8F64-41C2-BE12-2229AE73166C
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s2 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Volume2 (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Reserve:          214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Quota:            214748364800 B (214.7 GB) (100.0% reached)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk3s3 CF531006-42ED-46A9-9350-338DEFB95A42
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s3 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Volume3 (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Reserve:          214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Quota:            214748364800 B (214.7 GB) (100.0% reached)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk3s4 5EFD57F0-3FA1-4B7E-B617-B157F8CDFE92
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s4 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Volume4 (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Reserve:          214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
    |   Capacity Quota:            214748364800 B (214.7 GB) (100.0% reached)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk3s5 DDA13866-9C0C-4684-9A79-2428648DAAE7
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s5 (No specific role)
        Name:                      Volume5 (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               Not Mounted
        Capacity Consumed:         214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
        Capacity Reserve:          214748364800 B (214.7 GB)
        Capacity Quota:            214748364800 B (214.7 GB) (100.0% reached)
        Sealed:                    No
        FileVault:                 No
```